# Springboot : @RequestParam in controller reads the request with '&' and '#' as empty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, urlencode

I have a **Spring-Boot** application running on a **Tomcat** . Within it, i have a **RestController** with request param. `@RequestParam` doesn't read `'&'` or `'#'` passed as query parameter.
For example, if I give `http://localhost:8080/v1/test?query=&` then the controller method doesn't take `&` as value

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/test", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
     public String getV2LocationByName(
                                      @RequestParam
                                      String cityName cityName,
                                      @RequestParam(value = LANGUAGE, defaultValue = US_ENGLISH_LOCALE) String language,
                                      HttpServletRequest request) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
--------------
---------------
 System.out.println(cityName);
}
```

The above program returns empty output for & and #

Why does spring limit these special characters , but it is not limiting any other special characters?
And also if use query parameter as 'Andaman&Nicobar', the query param is read as 'Andaman'

Comment: Have you tried encoding those characters in Unicode? The & is used in Rest for adding another query parameter, so it should be encoded before sending as a value for another variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ampersand (&) is used to separate multiple request parameters,
while hashtag (#) is used for bookmarks/anchors in HTML.

They are both special characters with usage and they need to be encoded if they are not to be used for these purposes.

You can find more information on the topic [here](https://secure.n-able.com/webhelp/NC_9-1-0_SO_en/Content/SA_docs/API_Level_Integration/API_Integration_URLEncoding.html).

Answer (score 5):

You need to encode your special characters on the front-end side.

I.e `'$' is '%26'`

Just on the side its a good practice to explicitly add the name in your `@RequestParam("cityName")`

Comment: For encoded characters, it works fine for #(%23) and &. Is this because springboot limits decoded sppecial character on purpose?